# Identify link values and change in a WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

This is the first time I have ever logged into wp-admin console, I know absolutely nothing about this website. So please forgive my ignorance if my question is very basic.  I did try to google, but didn't find any help.

I have this website https://www.vestir.com.au just published. The collections button on the home page is pointed to https://www.vestir.com.au/gallery whereas I want it to point to https://www.vestir.com.au/gallerycategory/ladies-wear.

I logged in to collections page and tried to change the permalink value from current value to the desired value. However, whenever I am trying to save the link it removes "/" and hence becomes unidentified page link.

Can you please help me how to change this link?

Many Thanks!!

Comment: sorry could not understand

Comment: I dont mean the last slash, its the slash between gallerycategory and ladies-wear is being deleted. Can I update somewhere in the db?

Comment: and update where? sorry I am looking into this console for the first time.

Comment: .htaccess file is not present  in the root folder

Comment: I renamed the file still it doesn't let me save it

Comment: deleted, still the same

Comment: ok, now its deleted, what to do next?

Comment: go to admin panle

Comment: settiing ->paramlinks

Comment: select custom and update it

Comment: http://www.wpoye.com/how-to-remove-trailing-slash-from-wordpress-url/

Comment: ok, selected custom and removed the trailing slash. What do I do  now?

Comment: ok please check url

Comment: done with url's modification. still Its not working

Comment: then some plugin issue

Comment: I think you are right. I am not able to update advanced custom field plugin. It's asking for license key. Does that mean the person who built my website should be providing the key or I should be purchasing it?